# Chaining linq queries

Tags: c#, linq

Attempting to chain linq queries due to creating a simple filter for the datatables in my view.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? courseId, string grade, int? statusId)
    {
        var query = from s in db.Students
                    join e in db.Enrollments on s.ID equals e.ID
                    join c in db.Courses on e.CourseID equals c.ID
                    orderby e.Grade.HasValue descending, e.Grade, s.StatusID
                    select new { s, e, c };           

        if (courseId != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.e.CourseID == courseId);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(grade))
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.e.Grade.Equals(grade));
        }

        if (statusId != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(q => q.s.StatusID == statusId);
        }

        query.Select( q => new ViewModels.ReportView
                {
                    ID = q.s.ID,
                    Name = q.s.FirstName + " " + q.s.LastName,
                    Course = q.c.Title,
                    Grade = q.e.Grade,
                    GraduationDate = q.s.GraduationDate,
                    Status = q.s.Status.Title
                });
```

Linq forces you to end queries with a select or group which is forcing me to put an unnecessary select at the start. For some reason this is causing the it to ignore the last select and just use the initial.

I've tried grouping instead by e.ID but that doesn't work as expected...

I'm sure this is simple but I'm lost, any ideas?

Comment: could you clarify your question?

Comment: You're not saving the `query.Select( q => new ViewModels.ReportView..` at the end, which is the result of what you try. Save it to a new variable and return the model you need. Is that helped you ?

Comment: When it's that simpIe think it's time to take a break. Chhers

Comment: after your break.. please up-vote the correct comment so we can follow the solutions better... i've already voted it up myself. thanks :)

Comment: Or ask for it to be put in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a helper function to simplifier complex linq

```
   class Test
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int? courseId, string grade, int? statusId)
        {
            var query = from s in db.Students
                        join e in db.Enrollments on s.ID equals e.ID
                        join c in db.Courses on e.CourseID equals c.ID
                        orderby e.Grade.HasValue descending, e.Grade, s.StatusID
                        select QueryResults(courseId, grade, statusId, s, e, c);


        }
        public ViewModels.ReportView QueryResults(int? courseId, string grade, int? statusId, Student student, Enrollments enrollment, Cource course)
        {

            if ((courseId != null) && (courseId != course))
            {
                return null;
            }

            if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(grade)) && (grade != enrollment.Grade))
            {
                return null;
            }

            if ((statusId != null) && (statusId != student.StatusID))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return new ViewModels.ReportView
            {
                ID = student.ID,
                Name = student.FirstName + " " + student.LastName,
                Course = course.Title,
                Grade = enrollment.Grade,
                GraduationDate = student.GraduationDate,
                Status = student.Status.Title
            });
        }
    }
```